# Gunicorn: Not able to start from a script

Tags: gunicorn

I am trying to run gunicorn to start an app but Its not starting up from a shell script.

Command:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/code/ && nohup gunicorn example.wsgi:application --name example --workers 4 &
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved by defining the Environmental Variable for the project and With below command.

```
export PROJECT_ENV="dev"
cd /home/ubuntu/code/project && exec /home/ubuntu/code/analytics/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi:application --name project --workers 4 --user=ubuntu --timeout=3600  --debug --log-level debug --daemon
```